# jquery plugin regex

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validation-engine

I am doing form validation using Validation Engine. I see that this plugin uses regex for validating fields. I need to validate a field where, if the user enters a value less than 10, then it should show error alert text.("The value should be greater than or equal to 10").

How can I customize this? How do I set it in regex. Its a learning curve for me now and also a newbie in jquery

Answer (score 1):

Haven't looked at Validation Engine much, but regex is not the right choice for this type of validation.

The following seems to be the rule you're looking for:

`validate[required,custom[integer],min[10]]`